# How can I fix C++ error C2672 in my code with threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, invoke

When I'm trying to compile program with threads, C2672 error ('invoke': no matching overloaded function found) is occuring.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
// the procedure for array 2 filling
void bar(int sum2)
{
    for (int i = 100000; i < 200000; i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + (i + 1);
        std::cout << sum2;
    }
}
int main()
{
    // the second counter initialization
    int sum2 = 0;
    // the constructor for the thread
    std::cout << "staring thread2...\n";
    std::thread thread(bar);
    // the thread detaching
    thread.detach();
    // the first counter initialization
    int sum1 = 0;
    // filling of the first array
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + (i + 1);
        // elements output
        std::cout << sum1;
    }
}
```

Tell me please, how to fix this bug?

Comment: Your function `bar()` has the signature `void(int)`. In the construction of `thread`, you pass `bar` but you don't pass an argument for `bar()`. Thus, the function `bar()` cannot be called inside the `std::thread` as there is no argument for parameter `sum2`. It should be `std::thread thread(bar, sum2);` or `std::thread thread(bar, 0);` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value to the thread you're creating,

`std::thread thread(bar, N);`

where N is the integer value, as you've defined in your `void bar(int)` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// the procedure for array 2 filling
void bar(int sum2)
{
    for (int i = 100000; i < 200000; i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + (i + 1);
        std::cout << sum2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // the second counter initialization
    int sum2 = 0;
    // the constructor for the thread
    std::cout << "staring thread2...\n";
    std::thread thread(bar, 100);
    // the thread detaching
    thread.detach();
    // the first counter initialization
    int sum1 = 0;
    // filling of the first array
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + (i + 1);
        // elements output
        std::cout << sum1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of OPs function `bar()` is:

```
void bar(int sum2)
```

Hence, when the function is passed to `std::thread`, an argument is required to initialize `bar()` functions parameter `int sum2`.

When `std::thread` tries to invoke `bar()` internally, it does so without any argument but there is no overload of `bar()` without an argument. Hence, the error

```
C2672 error ('invoke': no matching overloaded function found)
```

Instead of `std::thread thread(bar);` it should be `std::thread thread(bar, sum2);` or `std::thread thread(bar, 0);` or something similar.

The fixed example of OP (with some other minor adjustments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

// the procedure for array 2 filling
void bar(int sum2)
{
    for (int i = 10/*0000*/; i < 20/*0000*/; i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + (i + 1);
        std::cout << (std::ostringstream() << " 2: " << sum2).str();
    }
}
int main()
{
    // the second counter initialization
    //int sum2 = 0; // UNUSED
    // the constructor for the thread
    std::cout << "staring thread2...\n";
    std::thread thread(bar, 0);
    // the thread detaching
    thread.detach();
    // the first counter initialization
    int sum1 = 0;
    // filling of the first array
    for (int i = 0; i < 10/*0000*/; i++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + (i + 1);
        // elements output
        std::cout << (std::ostringstream() << " 1: " << sum1).str();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
staring thread2...
 1: 1 1: 3 1: 6 1: 10 1: 15 1: 21 1: 28 1: 36 1: 45 1: 55 2: 11 2: 23 2: 36 2: 50 2: 65 2: 81 2: 98 2: 116 2: 135 2: 155
```

[Live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3902453f39630981)